# Twitter Bootstrap Icon Issues in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is a very cool, but for some reason all icons (and icons inside buttons) are not serving up at all in IE 7 & 8.

All that is coming up is a square symbol.

I can live with non-rounded boxes in IE, but the icons are kind of a must. Any ideas?

(if it makes any difference, we're running rails as the platform with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have declared the doctype in your HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the icons are correctly served on other web browser and you are using 2.0.4.

You can try to clear the ie cache.

Or maybe http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ (ie7 is supported)

There's a list of issue specific to ie on GitHub : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues?labels=ie&page=1&state=closed
But don't see any related to your problem.

If none of the answer make sense to you, post some code (jsFiddle would be ideal but since the picture is expected to be in /img it will not works without editing bootstrap.css)

Comment: thanks for the pointers. i'm going to have a look at font-awesome as an alternative if i cant get bootstrap working.